# How to add a specific timepoint in ggsurvplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, axes, survival, survminer

I want to break my survival plot and risk table in 7 days, but the follow-up ends at 90 days and I also want to include a tick at 90 days.
By default, the plot ends at 84 days when breaking time by 7 days.

Adding a custom x axis is not sufficient as it should be reflected in the risk table and cumulated events table as well.

I have seen that this can be done (attached image). Do anyone know how?

Example code:

```
ggsurvplot(fit_death, data=data, conf.int=T, xlab="Days", risk.table=T, 
xlim = c(0, 90), ylim=c(0,1), break.time.by=7)
```

[image: Desired output: ggsurvplot with 7-day timebreak and day 90 added]

Comment: A ggsurvplot consists of 3 objects, each of which can be edited manually. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61371184/specifying-custom-time-points-for-survival-plot) gives a good example how you can set time points according to your needs. Maybe it helps.

Comment: Thank you, the workaround in the link solves the problem.